# Comparison of quoted symbols fails using equal

Tags: quote, eval, equality

I'm trying to compare `(quote foo)` with `'foo` using equal, but the equality is failing. Here is a trace of what is happening with my code. I don't understand why the comparison fails -- does it have something to do with the reader, or chained evaluation?

How can write the code to make the comparison succeed?  Thanks

```
(plist-get (gethash "key" table) 'type)
(quote ctkb)

(equal 'ctkb (quote ctkb))
t

(equal 'ctkb (plist-get (gethash "key" table) 'type))
nil
```

Comment: It looks like you're comparing `'ctkb` with `'(quote ctkb)` ?

Comment: @phils: Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Are they not the same thing to the reader?  I thought I could replace `'foo` with `(quote foo)` whenever it suited me, because the reader treated them the same. As evidence, see the middle line in my original posting, where "equal" says they are the same. The puzzle to me is why equality succeeds in the middle line, using my "manual" version of what is returned in line 1, but fails in the 3rd line, where the return value of line 1 is passed directly into the equality test.

Comment: If it helps any, I stored `'ctkb` into the hash table originally, even though gethash is returning `(quote ctkb)` as a result in line 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing `'ctkb` with `'(quote ctkb)` -- or `(quote (quote ctkb))` if you prefer.

e.g. Evaluating `'(quote ctkb)` returns the value `(quote ctkb)`, exactly like your `plist-get` return value.

`(equal 'ctkb (quote ctkb))` is certainly true, but `(equal 'ctkb '(quote ctkb))` isn't the same thing.

I presume that `(equal 'ctkb (cadr (plist-get (gethash "key" table) 'type)))` holds (and indeed `eq`).

To say anything more, we'd need to see the code you're using to populate the values -- I don't see any unexpected quoting being introduced when I set up a similar structure:

```
(setq table (make-hash-table))
(setq pl nil)
(setq pl (plist-put pl 'type 'ctkb))
(puthash 'k pl table)
(eq (plist-get (gethash 'k table) 'type) 'ctkb)
t
```

Comment: Wow, you are correct. I played around with how I stored the original values, and can get the desired results. And you are also right about `(cadr ...)` working, which pulls ctkb out of the return result. Could you please tell me exactly what syntax you saw that made you conclude that "it looks like I'm comparing `'ctkb` with `(quote (quote ctkb))`"? My eyes tell me the return value from line 1 is `(quote ctkb)`, not `(quote (quote ctkb))`. Or phrased another way, can the evaluator ever return `'ctkb`? (using a single quote, instead of the longer `(quote xxx)` which I usually see. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I see now. In line 2, the reader treats the single quote in `'ctkb` and the `(quote ...)` as the same thing, so the equality succeeds. But when I see a return value of `(quote ctkb)`, that's the evaluator (pretty printer) telling me that the actual result is `'ctkb`. So in line 3 `(equal 'ctkb <result>)` actually becomes `(equal ctkb (quote ctkb))` for evaluation, which gives nil. I've just learned a nuance of reading vs evaluation syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, when you evaluate `'FORM` or `(quote FORM)` (as the reader converts the former to the latter) the output is just `FORM`. Quoting a form means that the evaluated value is simply what was quoted. The evaluated value is not then quoted (again) for printing; you simply see the *printed representation* of the object in question. As you've correct ascertained, in your case you were trying to compare the symbol `ctkb` to an object with a printed representation of `(quote ctkb)`, whereas the symbol's printed representation is just `ctkb`.